# Problems with Polynomials loading from file.txt to terminal

Tags: c, file, load, polynomials

I have problem with my function. Basically I need to load Polynomials from file.txt to terminal.

Basically, I have several coefficients on each row, and 1 polynomial equals 1 row. When I try my output on terminals is weird. 1 coefficient does not print and neither does 3 line/3 polynomial.

Here is my function:

```
polynom* vytvorZeSouboru(const char *soubor, int *pocet) {
    FILE *file = fopen(soubor, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba pri otevirani souboru");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Number of polynomials in the file - set to 0 at the beginning
    *pocet = 0;

    // Find out how many rows (polynomials) are in the file
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            (*pocet)++;
        }
    }

    // Let's go back to the beginning of the file
    rewind(file);

    // Pole polynomů
    Polynom *polePolynomu = (Polynom*)malloc(*pocet * sizeof(Polynom));

    //  Reading polynomials from a file
    for (int i = 0; i < *pocet; ++i) {
        int pocetKoeficientu;
        if (fscanf(file, "%d", &pocetKoeficientu) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Chyba pri cteni poctu koeficientu polynomu ze souboru.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
       

        // Polynomial initialization
        polePolynomu[i].koeficienty = (int*)malloc(pocetKoeficientu * sizeof(int));
        polePolynomu[i].pocetKoeficientu = pocetKoeficientu;

        // Načtení koeficientů polynomu
        for (int j = 0; j < pocetKoeficientu; ++j) {
            if (fscanf(file, "%d", &polePolynomu[i].koeficienty[j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Chyba pri cteni koeficientu polynomu ze souboru.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    // Zavření souboru
    fclose(file);

    return polePolynomu;
}

void vypisPolynomy(const Polynom *polePolynomu, int pocet) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pocet; ++i) {
        printf("Polynom %d: ", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < polePolynomu[i].pocetKoeficientu; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", polePolynomu[i].koeficienty[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int pocet, i;
    
    const char *cestaKSouboru = "vytvorZeSouboru.txt"; 
     
    Polynom *polePolynomu = vytvorZeSouboru(cestaKSouboru, &pocet);
    
    vypisPolynomy(polePolynomu, pocet);

    // Memory release
    for (int i = 0; i < pocet; ++i) {
        free(polePolynomu[i].koeficienty);
    }
    free(polePolynomu);
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, including the structure you're using. And also copy-paste the first five lines (or so) of the file you try to read.

Comment: I did fix the counting of raws now its counting right but still can't find solution for the first number from from each raw from the file that is not printed

Comment: @Bradley Kohr, Please post sample input data. Also post output seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing one potential issue.

**Line count**

Code counts the number of `'\n'` to determine line count.  This is off-by-one if the last *line* lacks a final `'\n'` before `EOF`.

Alternative, count the number of line begininngs.

```
*pocet = 0;
int prior = '\n';
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
  if (prior == '\n') {
    (*pocet)++;
  }
  prior = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//  Reading polynomials from a file
for (int i = 0; i < *pocet; ++i) {
    int pocetKoeficientu;
```

...
}
// further use of "pocetKoeficientu"

For later use the variable "int pocetKoeficientu;" is outside of scope (only valid within the for-loop). Put it at the beginning of the for-loop:
//  Reading polynomials from a file
int pocetKoeficientu;
for (int i = 0; i < *pocet; ++i) {
...
}
// further use of "pocetKoeficientu"

Comment: But the the variable `pocetKoeficientu` is only used inside that loop, so there's no need to define it elsewhere. If this was a problem, the compiler would complain with errors.